# jQuery AJAX Which is better on many aspects, get device location on window ready or right before search function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, user-interface

I'm trying to explain it as clear as I can for I'm not good at explaining with words.

As the title says, I want to know which way is better to get user's location.
Either it's in user experience aspect, performance, or anything else.
I tried both ways and both work.
I just want more consideration for few aspects.

The case is that when users visit a page which has search function, is it better to get users' location just when the page loads or get the location when users use the search function.
I know that we are supposed to have not-opinion-based answers. So if this question againsts it, I'm OK to have this topic closed.

I use AJAX for showing the results.

Thank you.

~ I read and edited a few times before I posted this question.

Comment: Technically, there's no "better" method.  As a user, opening a page and it immediately asks for my location raises a red flag, so might be preferred to only prompt when it's required (and obvious that it's required, eg "find locations nearest you")

Comment: @freedomn-m So it only asks for location when users start to search. If we want to show a few results first based on users' location when the page loads, will it be OK? It's like showing recommended entry for new users.

Comment: Ok, I read "search function" as "enter a search value and click search button" - if you're searching on load and need the user's location, then get it then - which is still "prompt when it's required".  I'm only providing an *opinion* as a user...  there's no answer to your question.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you very much for the input. I'm applying it now.